# Set different mockReturnValue for each test in Vitest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, vitest

In my unit test for my react app I am trying to mock a custom hook that returns objects with data that gets displayed in the component and determines whether some other elements get rendered. I managed to  mock the hook useGetStatusPageContent but I would like to be able to set the return value of the mocked hook to different values in individual tests. When I try to do that via vi.mocked().mockReturnValue() inside the the tests then useGetStatusPageContent returns undefined. Is there a way to dynamically set return values of a mocked hook in vitest?

```
import { cleanup, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, test, vi } from 'vitest'

import { useGetStatusPageContent } from '../../src/hooks/useGetStatusPageContent'
import KycStatusPage from '../../src/pages/KycStatusPage'
import { kycTestIds } from '../../testIds'
import { AppTestWrapper } from '../components/TestWrappers'

vi.mock('@inet-client-management-fe/shared', async (importOriginal) => {
  const actual = (await importOriginal()) as NonNullable<unknown>
  return {
    ...actual,
    useLoadingScreenContext: () => {
      return { loadingScreenExpired: false }
    }
  }
})

const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return {
    useGetStatusPageContent: vi.fn()
  }
})

vi.mock('../../src/hooks/useGetStatusPageContent', () => {
  return {
    useGetStatusPageContent: mocks.useGetStatusPageContent
  }
})

describe('KycStatusPage', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <AppTestWrapper>
        <KycStatusPage />
      </AppTestWrapper>
    )
  })
  afterEach(cleanup)

  test('Should display SplashActiveAlert', () => {
    vi.mocked(useGetStatusPageContent).mockReturnValue({
      header: 'STATUS.PROCESSING_HEADER',
      message: 'STATUS.PROCESSING_MESSAGE',
      icon: 'info'
    })
    expect(screen.getByTestId(kycTestIds.SplashActiveAlert)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  test('Should not display SplashActiveAlert', () => {
    vi.mocked(useGetStatusPageContent).mockReturnValue({
      header: 'STATUS.CANT_PROCESS_HEADER',
      message: 'STATUS.CANT_PROCESS_MESSAGE',
      icon: 'bank'
    })
    expect(screen.queryByTestId(kycTestIds.SplashActiveAlert)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

I tried to set the return value in each test and console.logged the return value in the component I got "undefined" When I moved vi.mocked(useGetStatusPageContent).mockReturnValue outside of the test it did set the return value but I need to set different return values for each test